# Class B is inherted from class A but class B does not show atributes of class A

Tags: oop

Actually In the code below the **class B** doesn't show **name** and **ID** inputted by user. When console is compiled the user **name** is blank and some numbers get print like   *878464464566*   instead of **ID**.

I hope you under stand what I like to say.

```
 class A
    {
    public:
        string name;
        int ID;
        void set()
        {

            cout << "Enter your name:  ";
            cin >> name;
            cout << "Enter your ID:  " ;
            cin >> ID;
        }
        void show()
        {
            cout << "Your name: " << name;
            cout << "Your ID:  " << ID;
        }
        };


    class B :public A
    {
    public:
        void display()
        {
            cout << "Class A funtion: " << endl;
            show();
        }
    };

    void main()
    {   
        A a;
        B b;

        a.set();
        b.display();

    }
```

Comment: Add a constructor to the `B` class, and call `A`'s constructor inside.

Answer (score 1):

The b object does not get the values from the a object.  The inheritance gives it the same members as the class A, but not the values from the object a.  You might want to [overload the assignment(=) operator](http://classes.mst.edu/compsci1570/assignmentop.htm) as a member of B to copy the values from an object of type A.  Put this definition after the closing brace(}) of the definition of display() but before the end of the definition of the class B:

```
B& operator=(const A& source)
{
    name = source.name;
    ID = source.ID;
    return *this;
}
```

Once you have defined the assignment operator, you can give the object b the values from the object a by assignment.  Put this line between "a.set();" and "b.display();"

```
b = a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 objects, "a" of type A, and "b" of type B.

object "a" is initialized.  object "b" is not.

The fact that TYPE B is a derived from TYPE A does not make object "b" get the values of the object "a".